# Delay in livestream after some time?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, live, netstream

I am using flash builder for live stream application. When I trying to play using netstream
as:

```
  ns=new Netstream(nc);
  ns.bufferTime=0;
  ns.play(streamname,-1);
```

My stream plays well with 1 or 2 seconds delay...When time passed by, my stream plays with more than 8 or 9 sec delay...I want my stream to play always with 1 or 2 sec delay..What i am missing? How to achieve by playing the stream with 1 or 2 sec delay always even after a long time?
      Please anybody help me....

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody please help me on above question...If you need any detail about the question, kindly let me know

Comment: Please share more details. Which streaming server are you using? Is your streaming server on the same machine? What quality are you trying to stream?

Comment: I am using wowza streaming server..and the streaming server is on the different machine..Quality: camera.setQuality(0.275);

Comment: RTMP or RTMFP? For live streaming Adobe recommends you use the RTMFP protocol -- it uses UDP and has a lower latency then RTMP. Also, what are you passing in the call to `camera.setQuality()`? Your comment above passes a non-integer value (but this method expects 2 integer arguments -- perhaps that is just a typo in your comment). The 2nd arg for setQuality (the quality setting) ranges from 0 to 100. Finally, the docs say this method is generally only applicable when streaming to a FMS server, but that doesn't mean it won't work with Wowza.

Comment: Link to the docs for [setQuality()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality()) method.

Comment: Sorry that is only my edit mistake..Above code is only camera.setQuality(0,275); I want to set buffer settings in my swf in order to control delay....How to achieve this? I think quality is not a part of delay control problem for live stream

Comment: Note, you're passing in 275 for an argument that is supposed to range from 0 to 100 (probably irrelevant). Also, if you **don't** use RMTFP you will get some buffering. It's inherent in the protocol b/c RMTP is TCP based while RTMFP is UDP.